# Gmail is taking forever to load in Chrome: Why is this happening?

Tags: gmail, mac, osx

I'm using Google Chrome 12.0.742.100 on OS X 10.6.7. It seems that Gmail takes an inordinate amount of time to load (2-3 minutes) as indicated by the 'loading' circle on the tab. Some images may help explain what I mean:

[image: loading]

The loading tab is a pinned Gmail tab.

To determine whether this is something to do with pinned tabs and priority inbox, I'll show the following images that exclude these possibilities respectively:

[image: inbox]

[image: priority]

NB: This slow loading also occurs in a normal, non-incognito window.

I wonder if others are experiencing this type of slow loading and what the cause may be.

Comment: I have had this before I just cleared my cache and it went back to normal

Comment: Can you confirm if you're experiencing the same problem using another browser?

Comment: Same thing's happening with Safari 5.0.5 (6533.21.1).

Comment: Also same thing happens on [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/).

Comment: This got accepted as a bug today. Hopefully it'll get squashed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned, it doesn't appear to affect the way Gmail works. According to several different Chrome Bug reports ([1](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85861), [2](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85248), [3](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83583), [4](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83874)), the Gmail website is attempting to load a resource that is taking forever/not loading properly.

According to the bug reports, it has something to do with this `GET` requested URL:

```
Request URL: https://mail.google.com/mail/channel/bind?VER=8&at=AF6bupMV0YlyE96Mz6Y9tRg5NS0raR6ssA&it=3125&RID=rpc&SID=304CA2227E292CA5&CI=0&AID=9&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=2hn7zqydxypy&t=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

If you would like to take a look for yourself, you can do the following:

1. Open a new tab
2. Open the developer tools. This can be done by either going to Wrench -> Tools -> Developer Tools or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
3. Click on the Network button (3rd tab). You should see a message on the bottom that says "No requests captured. Reload the page to see detailed information on the network activity."
4. In the address bar, go to gmail.com and let the page load.

You will see the network tab fill up with the back and forth requests/information between Chrome and Gmail's servers. Once you wait long enough for the logo to stop spinning, you can see what resource was causing the problem and how long it took.

This is a screenshot of my network tab - you can see that the `bind` resource took 3.6 minutes to load:

[image]

Click to see full-sized.

Although there are Chrome bug reports filed for this, I am going to assume it's actually a problem with Gmail.

**Edit**: After watching the network activity for Gmail for the last 25 minutes, I'm not sure exactly what the `bind` request does - it seems to be connected to *everything*. For me, the initial `bind` request includes what seems to be **all** of my contacts, and then  a bunch of information involving `contact.talk.google.com` about those contacts. The `bind` URL seems to close after about 4 minutes and then opens a new 4 minute connection - this seems to be how Gmail watches for new emails. Mine had a bunch of `[noop]` entries, and then the email address and subject of a new email when it arrived.

I'm now wondering if Gmail isn't working the way it's supposed to, and the bug is with Chrome/webkit browsers that don't stop showing the "loading" graphic until all of the initial connections are closed (ie, right around 3-4 minutes when the first `bind` closes).

**Edit 2:**
[I filed my own Chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86232) with this information, if anyone wants to add to it.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I'm going to follow this up when I get back from work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Been a bit short on time. I'm reading through those four bug reports right now. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I filed a bug report too. Hope we see some action on this.

Comment: I added to your bug report. Thanks for putting it up. BTW, I don't really know how to accept an answer for this question but seeing as you put me onto all these bug reports, you get the prize! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this, but *usually* it does not impact the functionality of GMail; that is, it keeps "loading" but the GMail app is fully functional in Chrome. Is that what you're seeing too?

Comment: Yeh, functionality is A-OK. Just curious: Has Gmail become a massive beast of a webapp?

Answer (score 5):

It is probably because gmail uses long server polling to update itself and chrome shows that as an open connection and keeps spinning the 'loading' icon.

We found this to happen with our apps too, in Chrome only, which use GWT and long server polling to do 'server push'.

If this is indeed the case with gmail too then its the fault of Chrome not gmail. Gmail has already 'loaded' if you can see and interact with the ui elements.

Comment: [Haha, that's what I theorized](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16235/gmail-is-taking-forever-to-load-in-chrome-why-is-this-happening/16275#16275) might be happening. Have you filed a bug report with the Chrome developers? This behavior is fairly new, but it's apparently showing up in both the beta and dev versions (not sure about stable).

Comment: I filed a bug with my information, and mentioned your comment: [http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86232](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86232)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean:

1. If you mean 3 minutes to stop the "full" browser loading, but just few seconds to actually get out of the loading screen into the regular gmail interface...

   In my experience on different machines, OS'es and browsers, sometimes it stays **forever**. I assume it's a gmail inoffensive bug since it never gave me any performance or functionality hit.

   When it annoys me, I simply reload the tab and the "loading" stops until the next time it decides to randomly begin again. I'd bet it's related to gmail labs, tho. I usually got about 20 enabled.
2. Now, If you mean you're taking 3 minutes on the loading screen...

   You should try removing some labs. Sometimes they conflict with each other. Use the Basic HTML if you simply can't get in and you'll be able to configure them.

   The loading screen should only take more than a dozen seconds or so if you're using a cluttered or very (I'd say more than 5 years) old machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I often see the same thing. I just select the address in the bar and press enter (rather than clicking reload)... then it tends to reload quickly and fine.

Comment: I've tried this a few times now but no dice. I wonder why this technique has worked for you, yet not for me. Anyway, I've filed a few bug reports and I'll do some more checking this evening. Thanks for your suggestion.